# how to deploy ImageMagick on tomcat

Tags: imagemagick, tomcat7, alfresco-share, imagemagick-convert

I installed tomcat-7.0.59, after g did the deployment of alfresco on tomcat (share.war, alfresco.war, solr4.war), I also copy the two folders common and libreoffice on tomcat, after restarting Tomcat, the platforms share and alfresco running except an error that appears concerant ImageMagick, the displayed one is as follows: err: .convert.bin: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml '@ warning / configure.c / GetConfigureOptions / 616.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the XML resources are deployed to the system/environment. ImageMagick will search the following directories.

> From [Resources docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php)...
>
> ```
> $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
> $MAGICK_HOME/etc/ImageMagick-7 
> $MAGICK_HOME/share/ImageMagick-7 
> $PREFIX/share/ImageMagick-7 
> $XDG_CACHE_HOME/ImageMagick
> $HOME/.config/ImageMagick/
> <client path>/etc/ImageMagick
> <current directory>
> ```

I would highly suggest setting the [environment variable](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37290053) `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` to ensure deployments are consistent.

This would be a great time to ensure `policy.xml` exists, and had be adjusted to [protected against attacks](https://imagetragick.com).